# How should I cite the SRD?

Tags: discussion, dnd-5e, citations

For [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/97189/31634), as well as a few others, I've used quotes from the SRD as a source. How should I cite those properly, to help back up my claims, and prove that I'm not pulling quotes from my bum?

Comment: Note that the SRD (System Reference Document) is a document, so a page number goes a long way.

Comment: @Miniman - The easiest way to access it is via webpages replicating its content, and thereby ignoring the page numbers, so getting a page number is not always the easiest thing. I would agree that the extra effort in finding a page number would go a long way however.

Comment: Well, easiest is up to you. Those websites often have some fairly glaring inaccuracies, though.

Comment: @THiebert I'm with Miniman here--I don't trust anyone else's transcription of the SRD and simply use the document published by WotC.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I generally use a link followed by a blockquote, if the quoted text is central to the answer, or just a link if it's a less central example.

So, to steal from your answer, I would say:

---

[Haste](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/spells/haste.htm) says:

> That action can be used only to take the Attack (one weapon attack only), Dash, Disengage, Hide, or Use an Object action.

(This is identical to what's in your answer, except that I made the word "Haste" into a hyperlink to the SRD entry you're quoting from.)

---

But if Haste were just an example, my answer might say:

*You should try using buff spells (e.g., [Haste](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/spells/haste.htm)) to help your party.*

...without the blockquote.

Comment: Are magic items and spells unitalicized proper nouns in *5e* or are they italicized common nouns like in *AD&D* through *D&D 3.5e*? (I don't know earlier nor *4e*.) That is, is it the spell Haste or the spell *haste*?

Comment: @HeyICanChan They're lowercase italicised in the core books, Basic Rules, and SRD. (Though I'd argue they're still proper nouns, they are just marked as such using a convention different from the standard of using Title Case.) However, community usage seems to accept both, possibly since Title Case is both familiar, and faster/easier than figuring out how to make italics in any given online medium.

Answer (score 8):

I'll assume you intend to quote directly from the WotC document and not through a website's transcription. If you give the page number that helps, but if you want to link directly to a specific page in the SRD you can add a hash #page=*num* to your link.

For example if I want to reference the [Grappler](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf#page=75) feat that is included in the SRD I could write my link like this:

> `[Grappler](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf#page=75 "D&D 5e SRD p.75")`

Then if I want to quote from it I'd use a blockquote and copy+paste. 
Like so:

The [Grappler](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf#page=75) feat (SRD p. 75) says in part:

> You    have    advantage    on    attack    rolls    against    a
>   creature    you    are    grappling.

You could also link the page reference if you prefer.
The Grappler feat [(SRD p. 75)](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf#page=75) says in part:

> You
>   can    use    your    action    to    try    to    pin    a    creature
>   grappled    by    you.    To    do    so,    make    another    grapple
>   check.    If    you    succeed,    you    and    the    creature    are
>   both    restrained    until    the    grapple    ends.

Or use an inline link for more informal references.

Comment: should you link the citation or the name of the thing you're citing?

Comment: I would think just linking the name, as I did in my example, rather than the entire citation would be more practical. But I could imagine it would work either way.

Comment: Sorry, I meant just the "(SRD p75)" part or just the "Grappler Feat" part

Comment: Oh, I could see it working either way again. I just copied the same link a few times in my answer here, but I'd probably go with linking the (SRD p.75) for more purposes. I just added it in the rollover text in this example but I don't think there's a standardized system for it.

Comment: The page number thing seems to be a trick that only works in some browsers. Which one are you using for this?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The [Adobe Reader browser plugin does this](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/link-html-pdf-page-acrobat.html), as does Chrome (I'm on Windows 10).

Comment: Yeah, it usually works fine in Firefox or Chrome but especially on mobile browser it's not always reliable. However, you'll still be able to view or download the document as normal and if the page number is given in the text the ones who can't use the shortcut can still find what's being referenced. It's not as easy as a website that categorizes SRD contents, but still links to a more definitive source.